# Streaming data writings on HDFS with high-throughput

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, spark-streaming, read-write, throughput

I have data streamed from a high number of sensors (> 500) and I need to write this data on my HDFS. Sensors send data almost every 1 second, and the size of every pushed data is ~300B. The problem is that I already experienced that whenever I start pushing to much stuff on the HDFS with the append mode, it starts raising many exceptions and gets stuck. I need to find a way to deal with this huge amount of writings per second, like adopting a middle layer that stores the data and then slowly push them into the HDFS. I don't know if any DB would work for this, and if yes, which is the best one?

UPDATE: I've looked around, and it's quite hard to understand the limit and potential of different solutions.

- Apparently, technologies as [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) can handle "hundreds of megabytes of reads and writes per second from thousands of clients".
- There are other technologies, some of them built on Kafka itself, as [Confluent](http://www.confluent.io/), but how it improves the writing is not still clear to me.
- Then, there are other frameworks, named as "Logging Layers" (more or less), that provide this kind of middle layer managing the writing. Most advertised products are [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) and [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).
- Finally, Spark as it streaming component, [Spark Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/streaming/), which is supposed to manage somehow the streaming of high amount of data.

Now, my question is if anybody has ever had to deal with similar problems, and which might be a good solution for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with HDFS throughput, but since you mention a middle layer, I'll list some of the commonly used datastores in conjunction with Spark that generally offer high writes (I think you're trying to use Spark as well?). I suspect that most or all are capable of writing back to HDFS.

- [SnappyData](https://github.com/SnappyDataInc/snappydata)
- [MemSQL](https://github.com/memsql/memsql-spark-connector)
- [Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector)
- [Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/features/igniterdd.html)
- [HBase](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector)
- [Redis](https://github.com/RedisLabs/spark-redis)

What is the "best" one is a matter of opinion which is generally frowned upon on StackOverflow. With some digging, though, you can find benchmarks and what not.